# How to get value from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

For example,

```
ID  name  quantity 
1.  Test1 4
2.  Test2 5
3.  Test3 6
```

I want to get the all ID value which is 1,2,3 and store into database, can anyone give the suggestion how to do it and provide the sample code?Thank you very much

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{              
    string[] productName = new string[GridView1.Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        productName[i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
        lbltext.Text = productName[0];
    }
```

this is my code and i always get the latest value, for example is 3. But what i want to get is 1 in my code example. I feel confused and hope can help

Comment: You are getting the same value always:  lbltext.Text = productName[0]; getting the productName[i] instead of productName[0], makes difference?

Comment: I know that , I set like this because want to test can get the first array value which is 1 or not. I think is my code logic or concept has the problem.

Comment: With the information you provided I guess that, besides iterating through your rows, you should add then anther loop to iterate through your columns as well... Something like for(int j =0; j< row.Cells.Count; j++) { row.Cells[j].Text }

Comment: Can give some example that how to define the column of gridview and get the value in that specific column ? tq i Googled a lot still cannot get the answer or suggestion or sample

Comment: thank for reply, already get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have one loop nested in another, when you just need one loop. Something like this should populate the array of product names for you:

```
string[] productName = new string[GridView1.Rows.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = GridView1.Rows[i];

    productName[i] = row.Cells[1].Text;

}
```

It might be Cells[2] or some other index, depending on how your grid is set up. Not sure what you're doing with lbltext so that's not included above.

Answer (score 0):

if you add a break point and test it step by step, you are overwirting the value of lbltext.Text each time you execute the loop. If you only want the value from first row, you could eliminate the loop and change it to

```
lbltext.Text = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

In another case, if you want to keep all the value, you could change this line of code so it loop through the rows instead of cells.

```
productName[i] = row[i].Cells[0].Text;
```

Comment: Thank for suggestion

Comment: @ZTChuah not a problem.